# Cannot receive data through my GET response

Tags: json, react-native, get, arangodb

I am sending data from my database to my React-native application but when I receive the response from my GET request, I cannot get my data out from the response.

I have tried with `JSON.stringify`, `JSON.parse`, putting in response[0], response.name (one of my objects in my response), etc.

```
alert(JSON.stringify(response));
```

[This is how my current response looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ws0d7.png)

My response body have 4 objects, _key, name, email and school. I want to be able to see and save all these objects from my response.

Comment: Please post your relevant code so that we can help you. At this point unfortunately there is no enough information on your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using fetch and calling:

```
fetch('http://yourdomain.com', {method: 'GET',})
.then(response => {alert(JSON.stringify(response));)
```

Then you need to call a second `.then()` to get the body of the response:

```
fetch('http://yourdomain.com', {method: 'GET',})
.then(response => {response.json()})
.then(data => {alert(data)})
.catch(error => console.log(error))
```